# HomeKit sharing crashes when sharing home with guest. (Owner is legacy iCloud)

Tags: icloud, xcode, sharing, homekit

A HomeKit user has shared their home with me for the first time. They are reusing a very old iTunes/AppStore account to handle all iCloud functions... this means they are on the legacy "iCloud" and haven't yet taken the "one way upgrade" to iCloud for Xcode 6.

The issue I see is that once I accept the invitation, there is a spinning hourglass on my device that never finishes.  I've waited 4 days.

[image]

My guess is that the host iCloud account must be upgraded to the latest version, but there is no such warning that this is required.

Here is a developer screenshot of the iCloud versions I'm describing. There is a corresponding end-user dialog that could make more sense but I don't have a screenshot of that.

[image]

**Question**

- The terms "XCode 5" and CloudKit support might not be the correct user-facing terms. What is the correct term for an end user who may need to be updated?
- Can anyone confirm that "Xcode 6 support" is required for HomeKit sharing?
- How else can I troubleshoot this?